# Keep original documents' dates with PSFTP

Tags: date, batch-file, psftp

I have downloaded some files with PSFTP from a SQL Server. The problem is that PSFTP changes the dates of creation/update and last modified of the files when downloading them in a local folder. For me it is important to keep the original dates. Is there any command to set/change it? Thanks

This is the script of the batch file

> psftp.exe user@host -i xxx.ppk -b abc.scr

This is the scriptof the SCR file

> cd /path remote folder
>
> lcd path local folder
>
> mget *.csv
>
> exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PSFTP and after looking at the docs I don't see any option to do this.  However, you can use the `-p` flag of [pscp](/questions/tagged/pscp) to preserve dates and times.

[See docs here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp-usage).

(note it's a lower-case `p`, the other case is for specifying the port)